# Convert, cast or mark Node to/as Element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, types, phpstorm, webstorm

I have the following example JS which is working fine..

```
const mainContainer = document.getElementById('main-container');
const subContainers = mainContainer.querySelectorAll('.sub-container');

for (let i = 0; i < subContainers.length; i++) {

    const subContainer = subContainers[i];
    const subContainerStyle = window.getComputedStyle(subContainer);
    const subContainerPadding = subContainerStyle.getPropertyValue('padding');

    console.log(subContainerPadding);
}
```

My IDE (PhpStorm 2018.2.6 on macOS 10.14.3) is complaining however, that `window.getComputedStyle()` expects an Element object

This is because `subContainer` is a Node when it is passed in, as `mainContainer.querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList containing the more abstract Node objects of which Element is just one type

- Is there any way to get an Element from a Node with a `nodeType` of `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`?
- *or* Is there a way to cast the Node variable to type Element?
- *or* Is there a way to mark the variable as type Element?

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by @lena in the comments, updating PhpStorm to the latest version (2018.3.4) removed the warnings

As pointed out by @sergio in the comments, `querySelectorAll()` actually returns a `NodeListOf<Element>`

I guess the question still stands for more generic cases though!

Comment: can't see any warnings reported for your code... What PhpStorm version do you work with?

Comment: @lena, intriguing.. have added version and OS to the question

Comment: If I write this code in a .ts file then the warning is gone. Must be an "imperfect" implementation in PhpStorm when checking JS instead of TS. The typings on `querySelectorAll` implicitly say it'll return a `NodeListOf<Element>` but for some reason it falls back to the default in `NodeListOf` which is `Node`. Also if you explicitly specify the return type (`querySelectorAll<Element>`) then it stops showing the warning but that's obviously invalid JS.

Comment: Also using `/** @type NodeListOf<Element> **/` before the `const subContainers` does not work, the type checker still thinks it's `NodeListOf<Node>` for some reason.

Comment: Please consider upgrading - it's a bug in 2018.2 that is fixed in the most recent PhpStorm version

Comment: @lena Thanks, that removed the warnings, but I guess the question still remains

Comment: normally using JSDoc annotations is the right way to do types casting